# Tailscale subnet routing doesn't work on-site

Tags: routing, subnet, tailscale

I've got a Tailscale subnet router to 10.0.0.0/8 set up and when accessing from a Windows laptop remotely, it works great and I can access these private machines using their addresses.

The problem starts when I bring the laptop on-site, where these 10.0.0.0/8 devices are reachable directly. I can no longer reach them while Tailscale is running. Stopping Tailscale on the laptop allows me to reach them directly but I need Tailscale for other things so this is only a workaround.

I can see there's some issue around this subnet being reachable over two different interfaces, but I'm not sure why it can't just pick one? Are there any diagnostic commands I can try?

I think these are the relevant entries of the route table, showing the default route that direct requests would go through, plus the Tailscale-added route for 10.0.0.0/8 (which goes away when Tailscale is disconnected). It doesn't look contentious and I don't know why it wouldn't simply use the specific route over the default route.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.216.0.1     10.216.0.189     25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link     100.118.41.66      5
```

Tracert shows requests going through the subnet router, so maybe the outgoing route is fine - is the traffic getting lost coming back?

```
tracert svc.company.example

Tracing route to svc.company.example [10.70.12.249]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    12 ms     4 ms    19 ms  green-dog.xyz.ts.net. [100.115.216.138]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I've tested accepting routes from another node that is on-premise, this time a Linux host, and that seems okay, so maybe it is specific to a Windows client?

```
traceroute svc.company.example
traceroute to svc.company.example (10.70.12.249), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  green-dog.xyz.ts.net (100.115.216.138)  3.302 ms  3.244 ms  3.840 ms
 2  * * *
 3  svc.company.example (10.70.12.249)  5.636 ms !X  5.616 ms !X  5.566 ms !X
```

Comment: What source IP address do the packets use?